# Select only (display:block) element from list of items Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a menu and i need to select one particular element from a list of element returned by Jquery.

When i run on console :

```
 $("[type='subMenu']")
```

This returns 4 matching submenu elements.

```
<div type="subMenu" style="display:block">
<div type="subMenu" style="display:none">
<div type="subMenu" style="display:none">
```

Now, i need to select only the element having `display:block`

I tried

```
$("[type='subMenu']").css('display') == 'block'
```

but this give `false` as output.

and

```
$("[type='subMenu']").css('display')
```

this is giving output as `none`

Comment: `$('[type=subMenu]:visible')` would only return visible elements https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Thanks ! you solved it.

Comment: Be sure to have a read of the additional notes on the page @billyonecan linked to for some info on the performance factor of using that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have already pointed out the JQuery `:visible` selector. However, there are some performance issues with it, as pointed out in the [JQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> **Additional Notes:**
>
> - Because `:visible` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:visible` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:visible` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use [`.filter(":visible")`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).
> - Using this selector heavily can have performance implications, as it may force the browser to re-render the page before it can determine visibility. Tracking the visibility of elements via other methods, using a class for example, can provide better performance.

If you'd prefer to avoid those issues, you could use a native CSS selector, instead. In plain ol' normal JavaScript, this would do the trick for you:

```
document.querySelector("[type=subMenu][style*=display\\:block]");
```

Or, if you need to select multiple elements at once:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[type=subMenu][style*=display\\:block]");
```

I believe the equivalent in JQuery (I don't use it) for both would be:

```
$("[type=subMenu][style*=display\\:block]");
```

If the only style that will ever be set inline on those tags is `display` then you can omit the `*` from the `style` attribute selector.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
console.log($("[type='subMenu']:visible")).
```

It will give all visible elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter or pseudo class.

```
$("[type='subMenu']").filter(function(){
    this.style.display == 'block';
});
```